# Child ImageView Not accepting Parent Layout Width & Height

Tags: android, android-layout

When i change the corner radius of linear layout background image,child imageview remains unchanged with same width and height.

corner radius working correctly for linearlayout but not for child imageview

```
 <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                 android:layout_weight="0.5"

                 android:tag="3"
                 android:orientation="vertical" >
                 <com.polites.android.GestureImageView
               android:id="@+id/imageView3"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
              gesture-image:min-scale="0.75"
              gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
              android:src="@drawable/sample"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`

Comment: already tried not working

Comment: `fill_parent` (renamed `match_parent` in API Level 8) tells your view to become as big as its parent view group will allow. that was my suggestion

Comment: @DineshRaj whats not working? whats your problem?

Comment: am working on imageview zoom and scroll,so am using this (GestureImageView) libray all are work fine. But i want to set corner radius for that imageview

Comment: and whats wrong with that corner radius?

Comment: it's work fine in linearlayout but the new width and height not affecting the child imageview

Comment: i dont know what you mean but you should probably use android:padding

Comment: @pskink exactly i want image pinchzoom and corner radius for that view. Am using this(com.polites.android.GestureImageView) library for zoom function it's work fine and am set corner radius programmatically for that view it's also work fine my problem is the corner radius not affected for GestureImageView but am zoom out means the radius is set at background of GestureImageView

Answer (score 0):

Adding corner raduis to a view will not change the corner radius of its child views.You have to apply a that background to the child views seperately